# Extract a line between two lines of a file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have text file as shown in image.

[image]

I want to extract heading when it is appearing between two dashed lines (dashed line position is not fixed ). But while iterating not able to check previous and next line.

can someone suggest some idea how can i do this?

Comment: Please post sample in question....not as an image

Comment: Why don't you check if the line red is a dash-line line, if it is then the next one is the heading using a Boolean ?

Comment: @Hearner .... In that case it will also consider para graph heading as heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
headings = []
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    n_lines = len(lines)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith("-----") and \
            n_lines > i + 2 and iines[i+2].startswith("-----"):
            headings.append(lines[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant check the previous and next line while iterating, you can keep track of when the dashed lines were seen. When the first dashed line is seen you start appending text, when the next one is encountered you stop appending, e.g.

```
headings = []
start = 0
with open('/home/usr3/test1.txt') as f:
    for ln in f:
        # append to heading list
        if start == 1:
            # when the second dashed line is seen, stop appending
            if ln.startswith('---'):
                start = 0
                continue
            headings.append(ln.rstrip())
        # first dashed line, indicate to start appending
        if ln.startswith('---'):
            start = 1
```

For the text:

```
------------
h1
-------------
qww
qwe
qw
eqwe
-------------
h2
-------------
qwqw
ee
e
e
e
------------- 
h3
-------------
```

The output is:

```
['h1', 'h2', 'h3']
```